# Wordpress not creating database table on activitation

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'offline_card';

// function to create the DB / Options / Defaults                   
function offline_card_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $table_name;

    // create the ECPT metabox database table
    if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table_name'") != $table_name) 
    {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `order_id` int NOT NULL,
        `card_number` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
        `card_expiry` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
        `card_ccv` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
                 UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        );";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

    }
}
// run the install scripts upon plugin activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'offline_card_install');
```

I don't understand what is the reason that it is not creating database table on plugin activation. It is not showing any error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay. Might be issue with your variable $table_name.Write it into function and try once:

```
function offline_card_install() {
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'offline_card';
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue but its strange :/

Comment: becuase it's a local scope of variable,not a global. Pl. tick correct to accept answer if helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked $table_name variable returns anything?

Comment: I don't have debugger configured and using var_dump or die isn't working in plugin activation. When i do die($table_name). It says Fatal Error: Plugin coudn't be activated

Comment: I put $table_name in local scope. But it's strange wordpress documentation puts it as global.